# Batch script to update hosts file on boot-up using curl

Tags: windows, curl, batch-file, hosts

I am trying to get a .bat script to run on boot-up and purge the hosts file with a new one.

I have this working on Windows Server 2008 Standard X86 and it has been working consistently for over a year. I installed 'curl', hard linked it to System32 and schedule the following .bat script using local group policy:

```
curl x.x.x.x/latest/hosts > C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

Now I want to get the same script working on windows server 2008 R2. I have the same thing setup and it works if I double-click the .bat file. However, when the script runs on startup via GPO, it simply wipes the hosts file completely and I have to login manually and double-click the .bat script.

Any idea what's causing this? 
Is it a difference between Server 2008 R2 and Server 2008 STD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
curl.exe x.x.x.x/latest/hosts > C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts.tmp
move C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts.tmp C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

Comment: Thanks James, this worked.  

I'm not sure why it worked though since curl was still able to make the hosts file blank, just not populated it with data.

Comment: @NullPointer - Since curl was accessing the hosts file, cmd couldn't write to it, possibly corrupting it. (Yeah, I know, "How do you corrupt an empty file?" Search me.)